# Tangent space to a product manifold using curves

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

This is an exercise from An introduction to Manifolds by Loring Tu.

> If $M,N$ are manifolds, let $\pi_1:M\times N\rightarrow M$ and $\pi_2:M\times N\rightarrow N$ be two projections. Prove that for $(p,q)\in M\times N$, $$(\pi_{1*},\pi_{2*}):T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)\rightarrow T_pM\times T_qN$$
>   is an isomorphism.

Let $X_{(p,q)}\in T_{(p,q)}M\times N$ i.e., there exists $c:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\rightarrow M\times N$ such that $c(0)=(p,q)$ and $c'(0)=X_{(p,q)}$.

We have composition maps $c_1=\pi_1\circ c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M$
and $c_2=\pi_2\circ c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow N$ such that $c_1(0)=p$ and $c_2(0)=q$. So, we have $c_1'(0)\in T_pM$ and $c_2'(0)\in T_qN$.

So, we define the map $T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)\rightarrow T_pM\times T_qN$
as $X_{p,q}=c'(0)\mapsto (c_1'(0),c_2'(0))=(X_p,X_q)$.

It remains to prove that this map is an isomorphism.

Let $(X_p.Y_q)\in T_pM\times T_qN$ i.e., there exists $\tau_1:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M$ such that 
$\tau_1(0)=p,\tau_1'(0)=X_p$ and $\tau_2:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow N$ such that 
$\tau_2(0)=p,\tau_2'(0)=Y_q$. This $\tau_1,\tau_2$ gives $c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M\times N$ defined as 
$t\mapsto(\tau_1(t),\tau_2(t))$ and $c(0)=(\tau_1(0),\tau_2(0))=(p,q)$ and 
$$((\pi_1\circ c)'(0),(\pi_2\circ c)'(0))=(\tau_1'(0),\tau_2'(0))=(X_p,Y_q).$$
So, the above map is surjective.

Let $c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M\times N$ with
$c'(0)\in T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)$ be such that 
$$((\pi_1\circ c)'(0),(\pi_2\circ c)'(0))=(0,0).$$
We need to prove that $c'(0)=\in T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)$  i.e., to prove 
$c'(0)(f)=0$ i.e., $$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0 (f\circ c)=0$$
for all $f\in C_{(p,q)}^{\infty}(M\times N)$.

Given $f\in C_{(p,q)}^{\infty}(M\times N)$ we have $f_1:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $m\mapsto f(m,q)$ and 
$f_2:N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $n\mapsto f(p,n)$. Then, $f_1\in C_p^\infty M$ and $f_2\in C_q^\infty N$.
As $(\pi_1\circ \eta_1)'(0)=0$, we have $(\pi_1\circ c)'(0)(f_1)=0$
i.e., $$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(f_1\circ \pi_1\circ c)=0.$$
Similarly, we have $$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}(f_2\circ \pi_2\circ c)=0.$$

I am stuck here. Any suggestion for this approach is welcome.

Comment: A simple dimensionality argument should suffice. You have a surjective linear map between two vector spaces of the same dimension.

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. @mathguy I want to get my hands dirty with this calculations just to make sure I understand details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is the chain rule. We have 
$$\frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} (f\circ c)(t) = df_{(p,q)}(c_1'(t),c_2'(t)) = (df_1)_p(c_1'(t)) + (df_2)_q(c_2'(t)) = 0 + 0,$$
as you wished.

Comment: your notation $df_{(p,q)}$ means $\frac{d}{dt}f(c(0))$?

Comment: Suppose $c:I\rightarrow M\times N$ defined as $t\mapsto (f,g)$ then, can you give reference to compute $c_*$ interms of $f_* $ and $g_*$

Comment: cello: one approach is to take a local coordinate patch around $c(0)$ as a product of coordinates around $f(0)$ and coords around $g(0)$. Then in coordinates it's clear that $c_* =(f_*, g_*)$.